# Will it take same amount of memory to load images to table view from directory as it takes from assets?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to load multiple images to a table view. It takes a lot of memory (cell reuse). I tried to manage it and used methods to deallocate view controller memory containing table view.

Image files I am using are in a PDF format which are only 25 to 300 kb files having much more quality than PNG/JPG. But when table view loads it shows around 600 mb of memory usage. I loaded 8 files which means it should take (8*300 = 2100) around 2 mb of memory.

So now I am trying not to put images in assets and store them in directory after downloading from server.

My question is: Will it take same amount of memory to load images to table view from directory as it takes from assets? (I assume it should read file data directly without loading it to virtual memory).

Answer (score 1):

A `UIImage` is a bitmap that takes "image width x image height x 4" bytes. This is true no matter the source of the `UIImage`. It doesn't matter if it started as a PDF or as a PNG. It doesn't matter if it was from an asset or loaded from the Documents folder (or any other folder).

So yes, your images will take the same amount of memory no matter what the source of your images are.

The only thing that makes a difference is the dimensions of the image.

Comment: can you tell me any convenient way to manage large number of images in table veiw, I read number of articles like to dealloc view controller so that memory dont add up. More over, I read about reuse cell but dont have a specific idea to make it happen

Comment: That's not a trivial question that can be answered in a comment.